# Different Bootstrap HTML markup on the site mirror

Tags: theming

I have created a copy, mirror of my site. Copied all files, export and import database. Exactly the same copy. However, the design of some elements is different, because the HTML markup is different. How is this even possible? Worth noticing that my default theme is Bootstrap subtheme, however, I am not rewriting any class at all. Even if yes, should be the same on both sites.

**First difference: menu block with the Primary menu.**

Original site:

`<ul class="menu nav" id="rm-no-id">`

Mirrored site:

`<ul class="menu" id="rm-no-id">` ('nav' class missing)

**Another difference: primary tabs.**

Original site:

`<ul class="tabs--primary nav nav-tabs">`

Mirrored site:

`<ul class="tabs primary">`

Also buttons are different, etc... Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You did clear the cache after the db import? Or at least truncate all the tables whose name begins with `cache_`?

Comment: Of curse I did, several times. Anyway, why would I have different HTML markup in the cache???

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily - but you might have different preprocesses cached, for example

Comment: I found out that the original webpage is using `bootstrap_menu_local_tasks()` function, the mirror uses `theme_menu_local_tasks()`. Any suggestions?